# What to do about an answer that's wrong but (in some sense) helpful?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

On Stack Overflow recently, someone asked a very interesting question about why she got inconsistent results when doing something that results in a stack overflow. (I'm intentionally **not** linking to it, the question doesn't need the meta effect.) She was incrementing then outputting the value of a data member and then making a recursive call until the program failed with a `StackOverflowException` (this is Java), seeing different final values of that data member output on different runs, and asking why.

Someone answered suggesting that she add a `System.out.flush();` call after outputting the variable. on the theory that perhaps the number of recursive calls *wasn't* varying, but the output wasn't being flushed.

The answer is wrong (adding `flush` doesn't make the result consistent), but calling the answer "not useful" (downvoting) seems harsh. But people are upvoting it, which gives the false impression it actually would be the answer.

What to do? Just handle it in comments? (Several have already commented confirming it doesn't work.) Downvote, as it is actually wrong?

Comment: @cVplZ: My instinct was *exactly* the same. :-)

Answer (score 3):

First, the theory. From the [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

According to the information you provide, the answer is not sloppy, the OP took some effort. The answer is incorrect though, so that would justify a downvote. The usefulness of it might level it out a little, so maybe you are withholding to downvote.

Let's read further:

> **What are the alternatives to down-voting?**
>
> If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.

Well, that is the option you followed, and that is perfectly fine. You can add a comment explaining why this isn't the real solution, but point out that the post does contain useful information (Maybe OP wants to clarify/update the answer or include some note that it is incorrect, although is contains useful information).

Posting a correct answer is a good option too.

Comment: *"Posting a correct answer is a good option too."* I'm really hoping someone does, because **I** don't have a clue why it's unreliable. :-)